# intel cpu not showing up as VGA compatible controller

Tags: debian, graphics, intel-graphics

I am trying to set up a virtual machine with gfx_passthru.
My system has an nvidia graphics card and a 4790k cpu.
The nvidia cpu shows up properly as a VGA controller,
but I don't want to use this to power my VM,
I instead would like to use the integrated graphics on my cpu.

My problem is my cpu does not show up as a VGA compatible controller.
I have installed xserver-xorg-video-intel and rebooted,
but it still does not show up.

Edit:

I went into my bios and enabled vt-d and set another bios setting so the gpu is used for my monitors.